# Почему java получает null из js?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

Есть JavaScript-функция которая пересылает данные формы в Java Servlet.
**JavaScript:**

```
function getAnswer(obj){
    let form = document.getElementById(obj.id).parentElement;
    let data = {
        qId: form.elements['qId'].value,
        qTypeId: form.elements['qTypeId'].value,
        chanses: []
    }
    if (data.qTypeId==1||data.qTypeId==2) {
        let chanses = form.elements['chans'];
        for (let i = 0; i < chanses.length; i++) {
            if (chanses[i].checked) {
                data.chanses.push(chanses[i].value);
            }
        }
    } else if(data.qTypeId==3){
        let chans = form.elements['chans'];
        data.chanses.push(chans.value);
    }
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(data));
    fetch('setAnswer', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    }).then(response=>{
        console.log(data)
    }).catch(error=>{
        console.error(error)
    });
}
```

**Java:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jsonData = req.getParameter("data");
            System.out.println(jsonData);
            if (jsonData!=null && !jsonData.isEmpty()) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                System.out.println(jsonObject);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

В итоге Java получает `null` из `req.getParameter("data")`, и соответственно не может обработать данные, подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка и как ее решить.

Comment: Так вы же ему в `resp` ничего не возвращаете, вот и нулл. Вы ответ в STDOUT пишете зачем то

Comment: Я может не совсем понятно сформулировал вопрос, или может я вас не понял. Мне надо в сервлете Java получить JS-обьект в виде JSON из функции JS, однако в конечном итоге я получаю null именно в Java, при том что объект формируется правильно.

Comment: Если req.getParameter не кидает NPE, значит req не null. Можно ли взглянуть на его дамп? Может быть там косяк с вложенностью?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен путем смены подхода к отправке данных с использованием JQuery `$.ajax`. Теперь данные отправляются нормально.
**JS:**

```
function getAnswer(obj){
    let form = document.getElementById(obj.id).parentElement
    let data={
        qId: form.elements['qId'].value,
        qTypeId: form.elements['qTypeId'].value,
        chanses: []
    }
    if (data.qTypeId==1||data.qTypeId==2) {
        let chanses = form.elements['chans'];
        for (let i = 0; i < chanses.length; i++) {
            if (chanses[i].checked) {
                data.chanses.push(chanses[i].value);
            }
        }
    } else if(data.qTypeId==3){
        let chans = form.elements['chans'];
        data.chanses.push(chans.value);
    }
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "setAnswer",
        data: {
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        }
    });
}
```

Почему была проблема с `fetch()` не знаю, главное что теперь все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, ошибка в элементе form и он не находит элементы с таким name внутри себя, либо функция отрабатывает до заполнения элементов формы и все value равны null

Comment: С form все в порядке, функция записана в ```<input type="button" onclick="getAnswer(this)">```, JS необходимые поля находит и формирует JSON-строку, которую я почему-то не могу получить в Java

Comment: Попробуйте в старую функцию внутри fetch в body отправить сразу объект data: JSON.stringify(data)